# Get sum of database sizes?

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query :-

```
SELECT table_schema AS "Database", 
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Size (GB)" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Which returns the database and it's sizes in the following way :-

```
Database      Size(Gb)
db_1          1.96
db_2          0.88
db_3          3.99
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
```

How do i get the total sum of the sizes of the databases?

Answer (score 0):

Append after the `GROUP BY table_schema`:

```
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html for more details.